# xpath splitting string by <br> tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am having a problem with python and the Scrappy library. When this code:

```
self.item['char_SP4_TIP'] = response.xpath('//p[contains(@class, "spell-tooltip")]/text()').extract()
```

runs, it extracts the text from the paragraph but it splits it by the `<br> tags`.

So instead of being able to access it like: `self.item['char_SP4_TIP'][0]`, I have to access `[0][1][2]` etc.. for however many `<br>` tags there are. Is there any way to fix it so it does not split it by the `<br>` tags? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the relevant HTML that you're parsing? Also, how many such `<p>` tags are on the page?

Comment: Ya, a piece would look like: <p class='spell-description'>
      blah blah blah blah blah blah.<br><br>blah2 blah2 blah2 blah2 </p>. Scrapping that would split it into 2 sections because of the <br><br> tags. I just need to keep them together and then I can replace the <br> tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your xpath selects all text nodes, but a `<br>` is not a text node.

```html
<p class='spell-description'> blah <br><br> blah2 </p>
                Selects these ^^^^          ^^^^^
```

You can `join` the split text.

```
texts = response.xpath('//p[contains(@class, "spell-tooltip")]/text()').extract()
text = '\n'.join(texts)
```

If there are multiple `<p>` tags with that class:

```
text = ['\n'.join(p.xpath('/text()').extract()) 
           for p in response.xpath('//p[contains(@class, "spell-tooltip")]')]
```